# PHP Access Multidimensional Array then insert values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$array = array(
  "id" => array("1","2","3"), 
  "text" => array("text 1","text 2", "text 3"), 
  "checked" => array("checked","","checked")
);
```

i have an array like this. i want to access value in foreach like this.

first loop => 1 | text 1 | checked or null

second loop => 2 | text 2 | checked or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array['id'] as $key=>$value)
{

    echo $value . ' | ' . $array['text'][$key] . ' | ' . ($array['checked'][$key] == 'checked' ? 'checked' : 'null') . '<br />';

}
```

**Result:**

```
1 | text 1 | checked
2 | text 2 | null
3 | text 3 | checked
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can be usefull

```
$array = array(
  "id" => array("1","2","3"), 
  "text" => array("text 1","text 2", "text 3"), 
  "checked" => array("checked","","checked")
);

// find the max count of multidimensional arrar
$count = max( array_map( 'count',  $array ) );
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        echo $array[$key][$i]."|";

    }
     echo "\n";
}
```

OutPut:

```
1|text 1|checked|
2|text 2||
3|text 3|checked|
```